# Sprout Forms notification test giving me an internal server error

Tags: emails, plugin-sproutforms

We have set up this particular Craft CMS site with smtp details and when testing from the Settings > Email page it works fine.
We've installed Sprout Forms and created some forms - all seems pretty good, but when we test a notification email from within the Sprout Forms admin area we just get an 'internal server' error. No specifics at all. just 'Internal Server error'.
Anybody been through this before?

Comment: If it's a Craft/Sprout generated internal server error, the underlying error message will be in your Craft `storage/logs` folder. If it's a web-server-generated internal server error, it should be in your web-server's error logs. I'd start by looking into those.

Comment: Hey @BradBell - yes it looks like a completely different issue unrelated to email. Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

As the original poster reported in the comment above. This "looks like a completely different issue unrelated to email."